# Creating a C interface

Tags: c, oop, interface, header

I only program in C occasionally so I was wondering if the following is a good idea: I have two implementations of a matrix in `linked_matrix.c` and `array_matrix.c`, which have the same public methods, so I created a header file, `matrix.h`, which contains the following:

```
#ifndef _MATRIX_H_
#define _MATRIX_H_

typedef matrix;

matrix* matrix_new(int num_rows, int num_cols);

...

#endif
```

Each `.c` file will then contain a proper definition of `matrix`, such as (in `array_matrix.c`):

```
typedef struct {
    int** rows;
    int num_rows;
    int num_cols;
} matrix;

...
```

I then compile the program with the appropriate `.c` file. I know for a fact that I will never need to use both of them at the same time, so the namespace collisions aren't an issue.

The approach compiles and works as expected; however, I was wondering if there were any glaringly obvious problems with this solution that a seasoned C programmer could spot, and if there are better approaches to achieve the functionality that I'm looking for, which is that of an interface in Java/C#: I can program against a set of exported functions, and I can swap out the implementation of the functions with another implementation without changing any of the code, only the list of files included in the project.

Comment: I'd say that if the matrix structure is exactly the same, then this is a pretty neat realization of the bridge design pattern in C, and it's fine to use it.

Comment: What if you put both methods in the same c - file and use #ifdef with friends to choose between the two?

Comment: That's the same thing really, you're just selecting which implementation to use by specifying a macro variable instead of a compiler argument. It's something I might do, but I was looking more for actual problems with the implementation that may occur down the line, particularly with the `typedef matrix;` part. Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: Seems good to me, but I am not necessarily seasoned...

Comment: Did you mean C++? C does not support OOP...

Comment: No, I'm programming the above interface in C. While C does not include features that we typically associate with OOP such as inheritance, polymorphism, etc. C code can be developed following OO principles, including information hiding, as I am trying to achieve here.